# Where is the source code of Android Image Cropper

Tags: android

I am trying to make an android image cropper myself. As there is a system image cropper(**com.android.camera.CropImage**) in Android, so I want check the code of system image cropper to know how to implement.

As image cropper is an internal API, so I download the framework.jar from a android phone and then unpack with dex2jar, then I got all the APIs which include internal API.

But there are too many files after unpacking and I failed to find which file indicate the cropper.

Anybody know how to find it?

Tip: com.android.camera.CropImage

Comment: Did you try `grep` on the source?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might be what you're looking for:

https://github.com/CyanogenMod/android_packages_apps_Gallery/blob/jellybean-stable/src/com/android/camera/CropImage.java